# What is the purpose for zero columns select?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

These are all valid queries:

```
SELECT;
-- 1 rows affected

SELECT EXCEPT SELECT;
-- 2 rows affected

SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT);
--1


WITH cte AS (VALUES(1),(2))
SELECT 
FROM cte;
--2 rows affected
```

and DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE z AS SELECT;

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'z';
-- empty

SELECT attrelid::regclass AS tbl
     , attname            AS col
     , atttypid::regtype  AS datatype
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'z'::regclass
ORDER  BY attnum;
-- internal columns
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c88419be9dacfb0df5405c66cf66b4a9)**

I wonder where zero columns select can be used (real-life scenarios) or it is just PostgreSQL language extention/syntax quirk.